# Laravel insert date created_at from 1 to 30

Tags: php, laravel-5

I try to insert data in my custom table

```
$month  = date('m');
$year   = date('y');
$number = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);

for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
    $test = new Test();
    $test->cuid = $user->id;
    $test->name = $user->name;
    $test->month = date('m');
    $test->created_at = '2018-04-'+$i;
    $test->save();
}
```

i try to insert number record in a month

let's say April have 30 days i try to insert it working fine but in created_at field i need insert 2018-04-01 to 2018-04-30 but this is insert only current date so that i try above but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set timestamps = false;

`$test->timestamps = false`

Comment: No actually I need to insert date from 1 to 30 in created_at

Comment: yes and to ensure `created_at` isn't automatically set to `today` you need to set the flag `$test->timestamps = false` and then set `created_at`

Comment: Is it correct what I have done but I need to add false only right

Comment: Correct, add `$test->timestamps = false;` before `save()` method